# What is best practice to declear and assign lots of TextViews

Tags: java, android

Hello so i am making an app which requires about 32 TextViews and about 32 ImageViews, Now my problem is I dont know how i can initialize and assign all of these neatly, Right now I am adding them in one by one

```
TextView textView1;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;
...
```

And then

```
textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
...
```

and the same with ImageView's. There must be a nicer cleaner way to do this, but i'm not quite sure how to do this.

Can anyone help me out?

Example of what I am doing(I blacked the images out) [image: Demo]
Thanks :)

P.S I have found answers similar to my question but not quite what i'm looking for.

EDIT:
I ended up using a GridView as sugected by Setu and Onur, Thanks guys :)

Comment: You are not showing all of them at once, right? Use a `ListView`. Also check this out   https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: I am showing them at once, why? do you know a better way of doing it? :) http://i.imgur.com/et7GjYA.png

Comment: well 32 is big number. `GridView` maybe?

Comment: 32 textviews and 32 images at ones sounds a lot to me. You should look for grids because from the image your UI looks suitable for grids

Comment: Right now they are all in a table, because I still need to set the Alpha on the images that are locked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for it is using GridView with adapter. You will not need to have vars for all textViews, but you will need to write your own adapter. In this adapter you can do anything with you view.